# When I call this method it doesn't work in java

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

When I call on the method "getName(companyName)" from the class Company, it doesn't send the user the name of the company from the yml, it just throws a lot of exceptions.  However, when i put in the code that the method "getName(companyName)" returns into the sender.sendMessage, it does send the user the name of the company.  Why is this?

Class where the method will be executed:

```
package me.ben.Corporation.commands;

import me.ben.Corporation.Company;
import me.ben.Corporation.Config;
import me.ben.Corporation.Corporation;

import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;

public class CorporationCommand implements CommandExecutor
{
    Config companiesFile = Corporation.plugin.companiesFile;
    Company company;

    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String     cmdLabel, String[] args)
    {
        companiesFile.reload();

        if (cmdLabel.equalsIgnoreCase("corporation"))
        {
            if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("test"))
            {
                sender.sendMessage(company.getName(args[1]));
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Class where the method "getName(companyName)" is:

```
package me.ben.Corporation;

public class Company
{
    Config companiesFile = Corporation.plugin.companiesFile;

    public String getName(String companyName)
    {
        companiesFile.reload();
        return companiesFile.getConfig().getString("companies." + companyName.toLowerCase() + ".name");
    }
}
```

The YAML File the plugin reads and writes:

```
    companies:
      simpleco:
        assets:
          cash: {}
          property: {}
        directors: {}
        expenses: {}
        liabilities: {}
        name: SimpleCo
        revenue: {}
```

Comment: "doesn't work" meaning... ?

Comment: Can you show the whole method where this if-else is located? I'm guessing you've got a scope problem. Also, what is the actual problem you're encountering? (Not just "it doesn't work")

Comment: @MageXy   I can put in the whole class

Comment: any error? did you debug?

Comment: @RamanShrivastava there isn't any bugs that the IDE recognizes

Comment: The difference is that the one that "works" (third box) does not first call `companiesFile.reload();`

Comment: @FredK I added the whole class.  I don't think think the reload() matters because I tried it with and without it.

Comment: @FredLarson By doesn't work I mean it doesn't send the commandsender the message which is the name.  It just throws exceptions.

Comment: What exceptions, for goodness sake?

Comment: @RamanShrivastava I think you told me to change it to static and that worked!  THANK YOU SOOOOO MUCH!!

Comment: @B.Howell -  My pleasure. You can mark the answer accepted and upvote :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your `getName()` method `static`.

Comment: How can it be static if it uses a (presumably) instance variable (companiesFile)?